# Markov chain doesn't sum up to 1

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

> Let $\{X_n\}$ be a Markov chain on $S=\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$ with the matrix [image]
>
> suppose we define a new sequence $\{Y_n\}$ by $$Y_n=\cases{1\quad X_n=1\vee X_n=2\\2\quad X_n=3\vee X_n=4\\3\quad X_n=5\vee X_n=6}$$does for $a=1$ this is a Markov chain?

I thought summing up and computing for example the first row of the stochastic matrix to better understand $\{Y_n\}$ so I did the following $$P(Y_n=1\mid Y_n=1)=P(X_n=1\vee X_n=2\mid X_n=1\vee x_n=2)=\frac{a+7}{10}\\P(Y_n=2\mid Y_n=1)=P(X_n=3\vee X_n=4\mid X_n=1\vee x_n=2)=\frac{3-a}{10}\\P(Y_n=3\mid Y_n=1)=P(X_n=5\vee X_n=6\mid X_n=1\vee x_n=2)=1$$but doesn't matter the value of a, they sum up to $2$ and not to $1$ means $$P_{Y_n}=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
\frac{a+7}{10} & \frac{3-a}{10} & 1\\
\dots & \dots & \dots\\
\dots & \dots & \dots
\end{array}\right)
 $$ Do I need to normalize the results? what am I doing wrong? Is checking that it's Markov chain is as simple as summing up each row or I need to show a specific path which doesn't meet the property of Markov chain?

Comment: You seem to think that $P(A\cup B\mid C\cup D)=P(A\mid C)+P(B\mid C)+P(A\mid A)+P(B\mid D)$. Not so.

Comment: @Did I think you meant to write $P(A \mid D)$ instead of $P(A \mid A)$ in the third term on the RHS.

Comment: @Did , why not? in our case $X_n$  can get only one value so the intersection is empty and the events are disjoint. So how then I calculate these?

Comment: Even more precisely, you are using $P(A\mid B\cup C)=P(A\mid B)+P(A\mid C)$. This identity is obviously wrong, in general and in the specific case at hand. (Unrelated: My guess is that you did not understand the posted solution, so why did you accept it?)

Comment: @Did an intractable click. The answer wasn't accepted.

Comment: (Sorry but the answer **was** accepted.) A hint that something is wrong with your approach is that, correcting some mistypings in your question) it leads to $$P(Y_{n+1}=1\mid Y_n=1)+P(Y_{n+1}=2\mid Y_n=1)+P(Y_{n+1}=3\mid Y_n=1)=2.$$

Comment: I understood my approach is incorrect but I don't understand how the answer proves it's Markov.

Comment: Should I understand that "why not?" in your first comment is now moot? And if indeed you did not understand the answer posted (something I *guessed*, you will have noticed), then why accept it?

Comment: It was a mistake. Let's don't moot. Now, Why his answer proves it?

Comment: It does not, but it gives cogent hints.

Comment: Coming back to this question after one month, it seems glaringly obvious that the OP did not understand the answer, one can wonder why it was accepted.

Comment: @Did why you came to this question after a month? Why it's glaringly obvious?

Comment: Did you understand the answer?

Comment: Fix me if I'm wrong (then I misunderstood of course) but since $P(Y_2\mid X_1=i)=P(Y_2\mid X_2=i)$ this distribution equals to the one $Y_2\mid Y_1$ and since that can be done for the other rows, we get that the dependence between $Y_n$ and $Y_{n-1},\dots Y_1$ is equivalent to the dependence between $Y_n$ and $Y_{n-1}$?

Comment: Comparing the distributions of $Y_2$ conditionally on $X_1$ and conditionally on $X_2$ is squarely irrelevant, sorry. (Unrelated: Please use @.)

Answer (score 0):

Let's write out the transition matrix of $X$ when $a = 1$:  $$\mathcal P = \frac{1}{10} \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 3 & 0 & 1 & 5 & 0 \\ 2 & 2 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 4 \\ 6 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 2 & 0 \\ 6 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\ 3 & 0 & 4 & 1 & 0 & 2 \\ 3 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 2 & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$  Now split it up into $2 \times 2$ blocks, and observe for example that $$\begin{align*} \Pr[Y_2 = 1 \mid X_1 = 1] &= 0.4, \\ \Pr[Y_2 = 2 \mid X_1 = 1] &= 0.1, \\ \Pr[Y_2 = 3 \mid X_1 = 1] &= 0.5. \end{align*}$$  But in fact, the same thing is true if $X_1 = 2$; thus $Y_2 \mid Y_1 = 1$ follows the above distribution.  And we can also see that the same is true for the other two pairs of rows.  Therefore, $Y$ is also a Markov chain, with transition matrix $$\mathcal P^* = \frac{1}{10} \begin{bmatrix} 4 & 1 & 5 \\ 6 & 2 & 2 \\ 3 & 5 & 2 \end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Why $Y_2\mid Y_1=1\Rightarrow$ Y is markov?

Comment: That's not what I said.  What I said is that because the distribution of $Y_2 \mid (X_1 = 1)$ is the same as the distribution of $Y_2 \mid (X_1 = 2)$, and because $Y_1 = 1$ if $X_1 = 1$ or $X_1 = 2$, then the distribution of $Y_2 \mid Y_1 = 1$ is the same as the above.  And because this is also true of the other four rows (the two other pairs of $X_1 \in \{3, 4\}$ and $X_1 \in \{5, 6\}$), then we do see that $Y$ is Markov.

Comment: Sorry for being a bit tedious but how getting $Y_2\mid Y_1=1$ proves it's a markov?